# Regex working in Regexr but not C#, why?

Tags: c#, regex

From the below mentioned input string, I want to extract the values specified in {} for s:ds field. I have attached my regex pattern. Now the pattern I used for testing on http://www.regexr.com/ is:

```
s:ds=\\\"({[\d\w]{8}\-([\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12}})\\\"
```

and it works absolutely fine.

But the same in C# code does not work. I have also added \\ instead of \ for c# code and replaced \" with \"" . Let me know if Im doing something wrong. Below is the code snippet.

```
string inputString is "s:ds=\"{46C01EB7-6D43-4E2A-9267-608DE8AFA311}\" s:ds=\"{37BA4BA0-581C-40DC-A542-FFD9E99BC345}\" s:id=\"{C091E71D-4817-49BC-B120-56CE88BC52C2}\"";

string regex = @"s:ds=\\\""({[\d\w]{8}\-(?:[\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12}})\\\""";
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(layoutField, regex);
if (matchCollection.Count > 1)
{
  Log.Info("Collection Found.", this);
}
```

Comment: Are the ``\`` in the input string literal backslashes, or just escaping symbols for `"`? **See [this demo](http://ideone.com/ZoEnHr)**.

Comment: Thats a raw input string that will be used for some further work. And hence looks that way. Consider \ as a character of given input string.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/XsW6dX

Comment: According to your demo, Regex considers  input string \" as " ?

Comment: Please try my solutions and the one below and let know which one works for you.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, your first solution works. Thanks

Comment: That means the solution below works too. Just do not use `[\w\d]` as `\w` already includes `\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you only watch to match the values...**

You should be able to just use `([\d\w]{8}\-([\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12})` for your expression if you only want to match the withing your gullwing braces :

```
string input = "s:ds=\"{46C01EB7-6D43-4E2A-9267-608DE8AFA311} ...";
// Use the following expression to just match your GUID values
string regex = @"([\d\w]{8}\-([\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12})";
// Store your matches
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, regex);
// Iterate through each one
foreach(var match in matchCollection)
{
      // Output the match 
      Console.WriteLine("Collection Found : {0}", match);
}
```

You can [see a working example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ljeer) and example output demonstrated below :

[image]

**If you want to only match those following `s:ds`...**

If you only want to capture the values for `s:ds` sections, you could consider appending `(?<=(s:ds=""{))` to the front of your expression, which would be [a look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that would only match values that were preceded by "s:ds={" :

```
string regex = @"(?<=(s:ds=""{))([\d\w]{8}\-([\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12})";
```

You can [see an example of this approach here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Ip0I9) and demonstrated below (notice it doesn't match the `s:id` element :

[image]

**Another Consideration**

Currently you are using `\w` to match "word" characters within your expression and while this might work for your uses, it will match all digits `\d`, letters `a-zA-z` and underscores `_`. It's unlikely that you would need some of these, so you may want to consider revising your character sets to use just what you would expect like `[A-Z\d]` to only match uppercase letters and numbers or `[0-9A-Fa-f]` if you are only expected GUID values (e.g. hex).

Comment: Note that `[\w\d]` = `\w`

Comment: Very true Wiktor. I've added another annotation in my response as `\w` might be a bit overkill in this case at it would match `_` characters as well. If OP wants to be more precise, they might consider using `[A-Z\d]` to only match uppercase letters and numbers.

Comment: Also, in .NET, `\d` = `\p{N}`, so you may want to replace that with `[0-9A-Fa-f]` if you want to match GUIDs actually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be over-escaping.

Give this a shot:

`@"s:ds=\""({[\d\w]{8}\-([\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12}})\"""`